# Rounding datetime to nearest midnight using Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark dataframe with datetime column in format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:SS`.

My dataframe looks like below:

| datetime_column | output_column |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-29 21:30:00 | 2021-01-30 00:00:00 |
| 2021-01-30 05:30:00 | 2021-01-30 00:00:00 |
| 2021-01-01 23:25:00 | 2021-01-02 00:00:00 |
| 2021-01-02 08:59:59 | 2021-01-02 00:00:00 |

How would I be able to get the `output_column` column from `datetime_column` column using Spark SQL?

**NOTE:** My data (`datetime_column`) will always be present between 9 PM to 9 AM so finding the nearest midnight is straightforward.

I am using PySpark 2.4.6

Answer (score 1):

Here's a trick that performs that "rounding" by computing the nearest day in second values (i.e, `round((timestamp // 86400) * 86400)`. It's the same thing I would do to round a number to the nearest 1000: `round(number//1000)*1000`)

```
(df.select(f.from_unixtime(f.round(
    f.unix_timestamp('datetime_column') / 
    f.lit(86400)) * f.lit(86400)).alias('output_column') )).show()
```

Outputs:

```
+-------------------+
|      output_column|
+-------------------+
|2021-01-30 02:00:00|
|2021-01-30 02:00:00|
|2021-01-02 02:00:00|
|2021-01-02 02:00:00|
+-------------------+
```

Note that the result above is shown in my time zone, whose offset is +02:00 (`from_unixtime` converts into a time stamp of the current time zone). If you need to have your exact result, be sure to set `UTC` as system time zone on your Spark config before running the code (this is [mentioned in the function's docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.from_unixtime)):

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "UTC")
(df.select(f.from_unixtime(f.round(
    f.unix_timestamp('datetime_column') / 
    f.lit(86400)) * f.lit(86400)).alias('output_column'))).show()
spark.conf.unset("spark.sql.session.timeZone") # unset it
```

This results in your exact expected output

```
+-------------------+
|      output_column|
+-------------------+
|2021-01-30 00:00:00|
|2021-01-30 00:00:00|
|2021-01-02 00:00:00|
|2021-01-02 00:00:00|
+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

A more intuitive way of doing this - you can use a `case when` to check the hour, and add 1 to the date if the hour is later than 9 PM. Otherwise keep the date and remove the time.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'output_column',
    F.when(
        F.hour('datetime_column') >= 21,
        F.date_add(F.date_trunc('day', 'datetime_column'), 1)
    ).otherwise(F.date_trunc('day', 'datetime_column'))
)

df2.show()
+-------------------+-------------------+
|    datetime_column|      output_column|
+-------------------+-------------------+
|2021-01-29 21:30:00|2021-01-30 00:00:00|
|2021-01-30 05:30:00|2021-01-30 00:00:00|
|2021-01-01 23:25:00|2021-01-02 00:00:00|
|2021-01-02 08:59:59|2021-01-02 00:00:00|
+-------------------+-------------------+
```

If you prefer Spark SQL:

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView('df')

df2 = spark.sql("""
    select *,
        case when hour(datetime_column) >= 21
        then date_add(date_trunc('day', datetime_column), 1)
        else date_trunc('day', datetime_column)
        end as output_column 
    from df
""")

df2.show()
+-------------------+-------------------+
|    datetime_column|      output_column|
+-------------------+-------------------+
|2021-01-29 21:30:00|2021-01-30 00:00:00|
|2021-01-30 05:30:00|2021-01-30 00:00:00|
|2021-01-01 23:25:00|2021-01-02 00:00:00|
|2021-01-02 08:59:59|2021-01-02 00:00:00|
+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: This is indeed intuitive but I don't really like it as it will fail the day when data is present before 9 PM.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way to round a timestamp to the nearest date is to add half a day (12 hours) then truncate the resulting timestamp to `DD` unit (day) using [`date_trunc`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#date_trunc). This will work independently from the time when your data will be present:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df1 = df.withColumn(
    "output_column",
    F.date_trunc("DD", F.col("datetime_column") + F.expr("INTERVAL 12 HOURS"))
)

df1.show(truncate=False)

#+-------------------+-------------------+
#|datetime_column    |output_column      |
#+-------------------+-------------------+
#|2021-01-29 21:30:00|2021-01-30 00:00:00|
#|2021-01-30 05:30:00|2021-01-30 00:00:00|
#|2021-01-01 23:25:00|2021-01-02 00:00:00|
#|2021-01-02 08:59:59|2021-01-02 00:00:00|
#+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Using plain Spark-SQL:

```sql
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('DD', datetime_column  + INTERVAL 12 HOURS)
```